# How to see what integers are in array of int options

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I'm working with an array of arrays, for example:

```
test = [|[|Some 4; Some 8; Some 3; Some 9; Some 2; Some 1; Some 6; Some 5; Some 7|]; 
         [|Some 9; Some 6; Some 7; Some 3; None; Some 5; Some 8; Some 2; Some 1|]|]
```

and am now looking for how to 'gather' all the integers, since I want to replace None elements with other 'missing' integers. So the first array doesn't have any None elements, but in the second I want to replace None with Some 4, since 4 is the remaining integer in that array. And to do that I have to first find out which integer(s) is(are) missing.

I'm thinking of something in the sense of "if element is type Some int, that's cool, but if element is type None, then for i from 1 to 9 check if i not in array and change None to Some i", but have truble writing that. Could find_opt from the Array library do the job?

I'm sorry in advance for the terribly phrased question, I'm new to OCaml and pretty confused in general. Thank you. :)

Comment: Are you allowed (I presume it is a school assignment) to use `Array.map`? If it is not an assignment, then with it it will be quite trivial. If you're not allowed to use it, then you need to write a recursive function that iterates over all positions of the array and writes back the updated value.

Comment: Can that array have multiple None(s)? Is the range always fixed, i.e between 1-9? Will the component arrays all be of same length ? Does the input array always have 2 elements?  Better would be if you can clarify certain things as such.

Comment: Hi, we can't know if this is a school assignment or something else and since we can't check it, even if you said "it's not school assignment" we couldn't be sure about it. In its current state, your question provides no minimal work from your side and it's not in SO habits to answer questions that don't show minimal work because we may be doing student's work fro free. Luckily for you, Chris provided an answer but you should provide some work (even not working one) when asking questions.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm really very new to this, but I am here to learn, not just get a soluton and hints usually help a ton. I'll add my attempts next time (I only added my string of thought in this case, because any code I tried to write failed to do what I expected it to pretty badly). But I did write the question in a way, that I still have a lot of work for myself. It's a tiny part of a bigger problem, that I'm working on solving. 
Thank you a lot for the comment, I'll add my work to future questions! :)

Comment: It's ok. It's actually better for you if you provide what you tried to do since it allows us to follow your thoughts and help you accordingly. As a rule of thumb, it's always better to have too much details than not enough ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how you can determine which number is missing from an array:

```
let rec number_missing arr range_start range_end =
  if range_start > range_end then 
    None 
  else if Array.mem (Some range_start) arr then 
    number_missing arr (range_start + 1) range_end
  else 
    Some range_start
```

We first guard to make sure we're still within the range we're looking for.

Next we check to see if the array contains the first number in the range. If it does, we know that number is present and we should check again, updating the range.

If the first number in the range is not in the array, then we can return that number.

Everything gets wrapped up in the `option` type to gracefully handle the event that no numbers in the range are missing.

With your array as `test`:

```
# number_missing test.(0) 1 9;;
- : int option = None
# number_missing test.(1) 1 9;;
- : int option = Some 4
```

Now, we just need to iterate over an array, and check if the element is equal to `None`. If it is, we'll replace it with the results of `number_missing`.

```
# Array.iteri (fun i x -> if x = None then test.(0).(i) <- number_missing test.(0) 1 9) test.(0);;
- : unit = ()
# test.(0);;
- : int option array =
[|Some 4; Some 8; Some 3; Some 9; Some 2; Some 1; Some 6; Some 5; Some 7|]
# Array.iteri (fun i x -> if x = None then test.(1).(i) <- number_missing test.(1) 1 9) test.(1);;
- : unit = ()
# test.(1);;
- : int option array =
[|Some 9; Some 6; Some 7; Some 3; Some 4; Some 5; Some 8; Some 2; Some 1|]
```

Scanning the first of the two arrays in `test` doesn't change anything because nothing needed to be changed, but we can clearly see the effect on `test.(1)`.

This approach works if multiple `None` values are present.

```
# let test2 = [| Some 1; Some 2; None; Some 4; None; Some 6; None; None; Some 9 |];;
val test2 : int option array =
  [|Some 1; Some 2; None; Some 4; None; Some 6; None; None; Some 9|]
# Array.iteri (fun i x -> if x = None then test2.(i) <- number_missing test2 1 9) test2;;
- : unit = ()
# test2;;
- : int option array =
[|Some 1; Some 2; Some 3; Some 4; Some 5; Some 6; Some 7; Some 8; Some 9|]
```

A rather imperative solution, but arrays lend themselves to that. I'll leave wrapping this logic up in a function to you, and suggest as a challenge you change the `int option array array` to an `int option list list` and solve the problem. That solution should be much more naturally functional.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you gave an entire solution since no previous work is provided in the question. Maybe give some hints to solve the problem but not the entire solution?